# In MQL4 how to get number of items in an array?

Tags: arrays, mql4, metatrader4

I'm trying to get the size of an array and found this code to do it:

```
int  ArraySize(
 const void&  array[]    // checked array

);
```

but I get this error:

> 'void' - illegal use of 'void' type    Test.mq4    81    10

Anyone can help  me understand what I'm doing wrong? I'm using MetaTrader 4.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone is new on MQL4 and fall with this like I did here is the right way to achieve it 
`int countArray = ArraySize(myArray);`

Comment: That's the array size, not the item count!